# Format disk as HFS+, but case sensitive?

Tags: osx, hfs+, case-sensitivity

Linux can format an (external) disk as HFS+, e.g.:
`apt-get install gparted hfsprogs`, then
`gparted /dev/sdd`, rightclick on the partition to format, choose HFS+, click Apply, quit; `mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdd2 /mnt/foo`.

But then you can't make both `/mnt/foo/xyzzy` and `/mnt/foo/XYZZY`, because gparted used macOS's default option, case-insensitive.  So copying files onto it from Linux causes all sorts of problems.

Can Linux format it as case sensitive?

Or must I plug the disk into a Mac to format it like that?

Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334330/which-filesystems-support-symbolic-links

Comment: If the downvote was because this looked like it belonged on apple.stackexchange.com, please note that I asked for a *Linux* command.  (And got one!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkfs.hfs -s /dev/sdd2
```

from `man mkfs.hfs`:

```
 -s          Creates a case-sensitive HFS Plus filesystem. By default a
             case-insensitive filesystem is created.  Case-sensitive HFS
             Plus file systems require a Mac OS X version of 10.3 (Darwin
             7.0) or later.
```